# Search Service Application result is blank for all except system account

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

Set up a search for this article - [SharePoint 2013: How To Create Custom Search Verticals](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34015.sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-custom-search-verticals.aspx), added a page I go under a normal account, access to the page is allowed for all, the search result is empty, under the system account everything is successful, what's the problem? What have I missed?

> **Errors:** It looks like you do not have permissions to view the credentials of the account for this source of results. Permissions are required at the same level as the source of the results. For example, only in an account with administrative privileges for the search service application, you can view the credentials for the result source created at that level.

Comment: does this normal account have permissions to view these result items?

Comment: @JoannaW_SPWX this problem for all accounts and where can I see it?

Comment: @JoannaW_SPWX Errors: "It looks like you do not have permissions to view the credentials of the account for this source of results. Permissions are required at the same level as the source of the results. For example, only in an account with administrative privileges for the search service application, you can view the credentials for the result source created at that level."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result sources can be created at the Search service application level, site collection level, or site level. This enables Search service application administrators, site collection administrators, and site owners to create and use result sources

To create/edit a result source for a Search service application, ensure that the user account that performs this procedure is an administrator on the Search service application.

To create/edit a result source for a site collection, ensure that the user account that performs this procedure is an administrator for the site collection.